# Android timer Stop and start

Tags: android, timer, android-relativelayout

I want to display the time since the activity was started over a view of map data.

Here is the timer code I'm using. I would like the timer to stop after 5 minutes. What do i have to add to this code to make it work?

```
package timer.tr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class timer extends Activity {
    private TextView timeView;
    private int hour = 0;
    private int min = 0;
    private int sec = 0;
    String mTimeFormat = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
    final private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mUpdateTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { updateTimeView(); }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        timeView = new TextView(this);
        timeView.setText(String.format(mTimeFormat, hour, min, sec));
        setContentView(timeView);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);
    }

    public void updateTimeView() {
        sec += 1;
        if(sec >= 60) {
            sec = 0;
            min += 1;
            if (min >= 60) {
                min = 0;
                hour += 1;
            }
        }
        timeView.setText(String.format(mTimeFormat, hour, min, sec));
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);
    }
}
```

Here is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0cWhB29uXURimKWeF3lASx-MHSdekdEUZ1oZ-MQ"
    />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Currently I no longer see my map view, I only see my TextView displaying the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
timeView.setText(String.format(mTimeFormat, hour, min, sec));
if( min < 5 )
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);
```

?

Comment: @koko You can't modify Google Maps. Your activity can use a `com.google.android.maps.MapView` to show a map to the user though.

Comment: i add this code to my project which already show  maps but when i add this code the map disappear and only the counting appear even the overlay items in the map disappear

Comment: @koko You should really make a different question for that problem. You don't see anything else because you are setting the content of your Activity to be the text of the timer. You need to use a layout that includes the MapView and the TextView, like a RelativeLayout to stack elements.

Comment: my mail is relative Layout !! but the Text View only appear the map disapper

Comment: @ jerome here i add to you my XMl Main what i must add ?

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it counts the time for which your activity has been running and displays this quantity.

If you want the activity to stop, you should stop calling `mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);` in your updateTimeView method when whatever condition you want is met. ColdForged suggestion meets your criteria

```
if( min < 5 )
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);
```

To get both your TextView and your MapView to display at the same time, you should use the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0cWhB29uXURimKWeF3lASx-MHSdekdEUZ1oZ-MQ"
    />
<TextView android:id="@+id/timeText"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And you should modify your onCreate method to the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    timeView = findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    timeView.setText(String.format(mTimeFormat, hour, min, sec));
    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_filename_here);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);
}
```